# A Summation Convention – Substitution Rule

Tags: summation, substitution, convention, kronecker-symbol

I'm new to this forum. I'm starting a PhD – it's going to be a big long journey through the jungle that is CFD. I would like to arm myself with some tools before entering. The machete is Cartesian Tensors.

I know the rules regarding free suffix's and dummy suffixes, but I'm having trouble proving the substitution rule:
δi j δj k = δi k

Assuming a range of 3 for each component, I will choose that the free suffix's have the following values: i=3, k=1. Therefore, using the implicit summation rule for the dummy index:
δi j δj k = δ3 1 δ1 1 + δ3 2 δ2 1 + δ3 3 δ3 1 = ?

Is my expansion correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your expansion is correct.  Now note that at least one of the deltas in each product is zero, so the sum is zero. If you set $i=k$ one of the products will be $\delta_{ii}\delta_{ii}=1$